# Extract Instagram Post description using Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, screen-scraping

Good morning,
I'm currently trying to download a certain field of an instagram post using Python selenium. Specifically, I'm trying to download the caption (description) of the picture (which, for example, in the picture below would be the section that starts with the text "Thanks @lolap ....." all the way down to the hashtags.

[image: Description]

I tried the following code, however it appears that it isn't working (it throws an exception right away):

```
caption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/div[1]/ul/div/li/div/div/div[2]/span/text()"))   #get all the caption text in a String
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is not working ? do you get an exception ? an empty list ? what does it return ?

Comment: and I'd recommend using css selectors rather than the full path. It would pobably be more robust

Comment: What is the address of the post you are trying to analyze btw ?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I'm not analyzing a post in particular, so one post could be: "https://www.instagram.com/p/CN-WqM_lDBG/ " The code above throws an exception.

Comment: How would it be with CSS, @Nephanth? I can't seem to get it right...

Comment: well in your example, the text of the post can be selected by "[title=Edited]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to collect all the hashtags?

Try this:

```
hashtags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='xil3i']")

for tag in hashtags:
    print(tag.text)
```

Or, if you are looking for the picture description:

```
desc_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='Edited']").text
print(desc_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
hashtags = soup.find_all('a', class_='xil3i')
for tag in hashtags:
    print(tag.text)
```

My ig posts' class is `xil3i`, but I get an empty value when using `.text`
. This code solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get the full description using the below:

```
    comments = driver.find_elements(
        by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,
        "span._aacl._aaco._aacu._aacx._aad7._aade",
    )

    description = comments[0].text
    print(f"Description: {description}")
    return description
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
                post_description_element = soup.find('div',
    class_='_a9zs')
                post_text = post_description_element.text.strip() if 
    post_description_element else ""
                print("Descrizione del post:", post_text)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).